# C18 RAM c-string - Withouth copying

Tags: pic, c18

In my C18 compiler (PIC, PIC18F66K22)
The following code:

```
char *message = "Test";
```

Leads to an empty string.
It's because "Test" would be saved in ROM, learned that the hard way...

But I believe it's valid C to do `char *message = "Test";` so C18 is not compliant with the C-standard or **how could I best describe this**?

Is there an easy (withouth copying from ram to rom or using sprintf to put rom text in a ram variable?) **way to specify that the text should be RAM**?
I tried:

```
ram char *message;
message = (ram char *)"Test";
```

Without succes.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `char *message = "Test";` and `char message[4] = "Test";`? They are very different.

Comment: `char *message = "Test"` would declare a pointer named 'message' which gets initialized with a pointer towards the first character of a (ROM?) string literal "Test"? And `char message[4] = "Test"` would declare an array named 'message' with a fixed length of 4, initialized with the chars 'T' 'e' 's' 't'?

So this would mean that C doesn't allow me to interchange RAM and ROM? Or do most compilers do this by themselves? I'm more used to C++, is it different there?

Comment: Note that not all microcontroller families have this limitation. It's not a C limitation, it's a "PIC C" limitation.

Comment: @pjc50 thanks, yes, that's why it's bothering me so badly. I think it's against the C-standard? And even on their XC8 compiler it seems to work. Never had stuff like this on AVR/ATmega328p chips. But would that mean they're less memory efficient? Or is C18 just lacking the standard of C/usuability?

Comment: C18 is certainly rather constrained. Harvard architecture is fractionally more cycle-efficient for processors without cache, but as you can see leads to this kind of messing about.

Comment: @pjc50 Hmmm, indeed, the problem occured when creating a string (for a HTTP POST message) with an undefined length (a function that could send messages of any length). But it's a complete different question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the HiTech C compiler, a `char *` will be presumed to point to RAM; a `const char*` will be capable of accessing either RAM or ROM.  I'm not positive that that convention has followed through to other compilers, but it's a useful and practical approach.

Comment: This, this is why I get so confused... on the identical hardware with identical code it has different output...

This is also why I don't want to 'fully' agree that it's due to hardware architecture.
Somehow I find the implementation of HiTech C more useable/logical. The only question left is, why does C18 do it different? Is this a performance thing, program memory being cheaper, as well a "string" is already in the program memory isn't it?

Comment: @Fua: Again, think of what you are asking requires at the machine level. Sure, you can create a universal pointer type in a high level language, but that then forces a lot of run-time checking and alternate code for accessing program memory or data memory. That could be very bad in a tight project, and then you'd be here complaining how you know you'll only use this pointer to access RAM, but you have no way of telling this to the compiler so that it can eliminate a lot of checking and program memory access code you will never use. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Being able to have general-purpose "string output" function call for each character a function which accepts a pointer and does either a RAM or ROM fetch is apt to yield smaller code than having an "output RAM string" and "output ROM string" functions.  IMHO, the proper approach is to have RAM-only, ROM-only, and universal pointer types; I've seen 8x51 compilers which do a good job with such distinctions (and XDATA as well) but I've not seen that on the PIC.

Comment: @Olin, but what when the hardware is the same, but the compiler different?  Agree, that no mixing RAM and ROM pointers will nog work, those are two different memory places and should this be handled different. But there seems to be a difference on how compilers do this. I wanted to know why/how but you want to say that it will obviously lead to far more instructions? Or that it doesn't fix itselve withouth the extra instructions?

Comment: @FuaZe: Different compiler vendors have different expectations as to how people will prioritize things like speed, memory usage, or the tradeoffs between control and simplicity.  Some hardware vendors make public recommendations as to how compiler vendors should support things, and their recommendations are sound.  Microchip hasn't really done that; it's offered its own compilers for years, but until they bought HiTech their compilers did not have a good reputation.

Comment: Yeah that's true and I fully agree that's the main reason to read the manual also.
So I should address this as a compiler 'feature' rather than a bug or hardware difference. It's going to be something I'm going to take care off because my compiler prefers these data-spaces to not to be bridged by extra code/instructions as they are also separated in the hardware. Which is what Olin is trying to tell me?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't lead to an empty string, it's just that the context in which you are using the string is wrong.

With the smaller PIC chips and indeed with most Harvard architecture chips, there are two distinct memory address ranges - the RAM and the ROM address spaces.  Both address spaces have the same address numbers, so it can get confusing if you're not sure what you're doing.

To illustrate, your string could be at address 100.  Now, is that RAM address 100 or ROM address 100? Both are address 100, but they each need different instructions to get at them.

Using a function that reads RAM address 100 will of course not return the same data as a function that reads ROM address 100, so your string will appear to be empty - or complete gibberish.

C18 automatically places all string constants in ROM:

> The primary use of data located in program memory is for static strings. In keeping
>   with this, MPLAB C18 automatically places all string constants in program memory.
>   This type of a string constant is “array of char located in program memory”, (const
>   rom char []). The .stringtable section is a romdata (see Section 2.9.1
>   “#pragma sectiontype”) section that contains all constant strings.
>
> Due to the fact that constant strings are kept in program memory, there are multiple
>   versions of the standard functions that deal with strings. For example, the strcpy
>   function has four variants, allowing the copying of a string to and from data and
>   program memory

So you have to ensure you use the right functions to access the ROM not the RAM.

Strings must be passed to functions in the right way to ensure that they are accessed with the right code.  All string parameters must be:

```
static const rom char *
```

Most standard string functions have extra variants, which either end in `pgm2ram`, `ram2pgm` or `pgm2pgm`.  Those that need just one parameter have the suffix `pgm` for ROM based access.

The printf family of functions have the additional parameter "%S" for ROM based strings (as opposed to "%s" for RAM based strings).

Comment: When I want my function to accept any kind of string type, I should make multiple functions, or one which will copy it to RAM and then use the RAM function... I've looked into the `pgm2ram` but this needs a length, and my function can't know beforehand how long the ROM string is that I pass to the function?

Comment: If you pass the string as `static const rom char *` then you can use the data from it directly as if it were in RAM (use pointers to the data). No need to copy it into RAM if you just want to read the data from it.  You could have one function that has two parameters - one for RAM and one for ROM, and you set one to a valid pointer and the other to NULL, then decide which to use in your routine.

Comment: Look at the `putsUSART_rom` example on page 17 of the manual.

Comment: So I can't cast one to another, and should make seperate functions for RAM and ROM? And then I'm still unable to define the length of them? Or are ROM strings also null terminated?

Comment: The only difference between a ROM string and a RAM string is that a ROM string is stored in ROM and a RAM string is stored in RAM. The structure of the data is identical.

Comment: Yup, I believe I can't get away with making separate functions for accepting RAM/ROM (unless there really is a universal pointer type as said by Olin) The confusion would be caused because C++ strings do not have different RAM/ROM (unless CONST) and even when CONST they 'can' (but should not) be used for other functions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a combination of these factors:

The C language was thought out for Von Neuman machines.

The PIC 18 isn't a von Neuman machine.

You are blindly expecting a compiler for a language fundamentally unsuited to your machine to just fix everything for you according to rules that *can't* apply to the hardware architecture.

This is the poster case of why you need to actually *know* something about the machine architecture when on a small resource-limited system, especially one that the language was never designed to support.

The PIC 18 is a harvard architecture, meaning it has separate physical memories for program and data.  In the PIC 18 case, program memory is organized into 16 bit words and addressed as bytes with 20 bit addresses.  Data memory is bytes with 12 bit addresses, organized into banks of 256 bytes each.  On some PIC 18, there is also EEPROM in yet another address space.

The C language only has the concept of pointers or addresses into a single address space.  Therefore, any useful C implementation on a PIC 18 *can't* follow the standard to the letter.  Of course this is all well documented in the C18 manual.  You need to ***read the manual***.

In this case you have a confusion between a pointer to a string in program memory, and the address of a string in RAM.  As the C18 manual clearly states, and even a cursory understanding of the architecture would lead you to suspect (and then follow up by reading the manual, or course), it puts string constants into program memory.

Therefore, the first line you show is creating the variable "message", which will be initialized at startup with the *program memory address* of wherever the linker put the constant string "Test".  This is of course not going to yield the expected result if you then try to use message as a pointer to a string in RAM.  Again, you have to actually know what you're doing on such small resource-limited systems.

Comment: 3. I would expect it to work as it did work on ATMega328P (AVR GCC)? And it also did in the XC8 compiler. Does this mean that these compilers choose to put it in the RAM? Theoretically, it would indeed be so that C is the same everywhere. I agree that the manual explains it, so it's practically not an argument.

I was hoping there is a way to specify that the text is RAM, as it's cumbersome to create different functions for each memory type? For every argument of a function I would have to make another function if I want it to be able to take a "ROMstring" aswell as 'regular' RAM string.

Comment: @Fua: Again, you are failing to think about how this has to work at the machine level.  Go write a project in assembler and actually *learn* the machine.  Ultimately, different instructions will be required to access a string in program memory versus RAM.  The compiler can't change that.  One strategy is to do a lot of runtime checking for you and pretend all is fine at the source level.  Another is to make you tell it what you want to do so that you can have efficiency when you need it.  I vaguely remember C18 may have a universal pointer type that does the runtime checking.  See manual.

Comment: Hmm, I might be confusing C++ strings with C strings? As I believe that C++ strings can easily be adjusted in size even on embedded devices (AVR)? But you say this is due to the run-time checking? And this is not in PIC-C for performance and/or architecture differences?

Comment: I think this answer is unnecessarily hostile. In reply to comments: I don't see where C++ comes into this? It's not to do with size adjustment of the string at all. It's about incompatible pointer types.

Comment: Second thing that confuses me is the answer below, it seems a difference in the compiler and not just the hardware? But I must agree on you that it's clear in the user manual. It's not that I don't understand the hardware part it's just that it seems illogical or unclear why this is different on other compiler/same hardware

Comment: @pjc50 Thanks, but Olin actually doesn't like people that don't read the manual (I'm aware of that and try not to take it personal), and it's described in the manual. I'm more wanting to know why this is so. And not on other compilers.

Comment: I think a proper answer really demands someone taking the various permutations, compiling them under C18 and XC8, and discussing the assembler output. XC8 may be using a spare bit in a pointer to determine "RAM" or "ROM".

Comment: Dag yo, if this OP *actually knew what they were doing*, they wouldn't be confused and asking questions here. Duh.